# Dealing with Tall, Thin, Skewed Data

Tags: data-transformation, density-function, beta-distribution, weibull-distribution

I'm working with a dataset that shows particle movement. There are three broad cases that I see in my data, when they are negatively skewed, approximately normal, or positively skewed. My end goal is to select a known distribution that can be used to describe all cases. I've been using the General Beta Distribution so far, however, it 'fails' in the cases where my data are negatively skewed. The PDF is below.

f(x)=[(x−a)^(p−1)(b−x)^(q−1)]/B(p,q)*(b−a)^(p+q−1) a≤x≤b;p,q>0

[image]

While the generated PDF covers the entire range of my data, the distribution is far 'thicker' than the data it is generated from. The image below shows this.

[image]

Can anyone point me in the direction of some resource that either:

a) Contains a probability distribution that can adequately describe such data OR

b) Contains some method whereby a distribution can be modified to account for this thinning

Thanks!

P.S.: I have also attempted the same with a 3-parameter Weibull and have had more success with the Beta Distribution.

Comment: Your "PDF" curve clearly is a bad fit--there's something the matter with whatever procedure was used to generate it.  Beta distributions can be negatively skewed.  However, your histogram clearly does not have the shape of any Beta.  But why do you need to fit some parametric distribution to this histogram?  What would that accomplish for you?

Comment: The idea is to predict particle movement based on 3 different input values which affect final position. The idea with fitting a parametric distribution is for ease of use with said parameters. While a non-parametric fit can be created, its not as useful to predict the final position. With using the parameters, particularly in the positively skewed and no-skew cases, they can reliably be predicted. No so for this case. I've tried a few other distributions but they all suffer from the same problem in terms of not fitting my data well.